# Does Phoenix Wright have voice acting?

Tags: phoenix-wright-ace-attorney

I'm trying out Phoenix Wright: Ace Attorney on iOS but it doesn't seem to have voice acting? Is there a version with voice acting that I should play instead or does the game just not have voice acting in general?

I only care about Japanese voices

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the Ace Attorney series never had voice acting, aside from the iconic shouts like
"OBJECTION!" ("異議あり!").

In addition to that, the latest *Phoenix Wright: Ace Attorney - Dual Destinies* features Anime style cutscenes with voice acting.